# PHP Hook Function

Tags: php, performance, hook

Can I basically do something like:

```
register_function_hook('myFunctionHook');
```

so then when any function is run:

```
functionA(); //The hook runs myFunctionHook();
anoterFunction(); //The hook runs myFunctionHook();
Class::functionA(); //The hook runs myFunctionHook();
```

Does such a thing exist?

-- Edit --

What I want to do is to get a breakdown of durations of each function. Ie. Performance Tuning. I want to get an idea of what takes all the time without installing xDebug on my Apache server, however I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Not AFAIK.  What are you trying to accomplish?  There might be a better way.

Comment: Check out Drupal. It uses hooks extensively!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, its not possible the way you like**

But You can achieve something close with inheritance.

```
 class Vehicle {
       function __construct() {
              $this->hookFunction();
       }

       function hookFunction() {
              //
       }
 }

 class Car extends Vehicle {

 } 

 Class Toyota extends Car {

 }

 new Toyota(); // will you hook function
 // this exclude static call to member functions, or other inline functions.
```

Answer (score 7):

It's possible with **[`register_tick_function()`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php)**, also [check this comment on the PHP manual](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#85290):

```
$script_stats = array();
$time = microtime(true);

function track_stats(){
    global $script_stats,$time;
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $exe_time = (microtime(true) - $time) * 1000;
    $func_args = implode(", ",$trace[1]["args"]);
    $script_stats[] = array(
        "current_time" => microtime(true),
        "memory" => memory_get_usage(true),
        "file" => $trace[1]["file"].': '.$trace[1]["line"],
        "function" => $trace[1]["function"].'('.$func_args.')',
        "called_by" => $trace[2]["function"].' in '.$trace[2]["file"].': '.$trace[2]["line"],
        "ns" => $exe_time
        );
    $time = microtime(true);
    }

declare(ticks = 1);
register_tick_function("track_stats");

// the rest of your project code

// output $script_stats into a html table or something
```

This "hooks" to everything, not just functions but I think it fits your purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, for my case, it does not hook into system calls. like `mysqli_init`.

Answer (score 1):

What you looking for is called profiler. And [PQP](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/) looks like one, which is standalone.

Comment: But with that it looks like I have to basically put profiler elements all over my code, which is not what I want. I was hoping to have some kind of register.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of polluting the code, you should use a real Profiler, like that one provided by [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if the Topic Starter needs this anymore, but perhaps others can still benefit from this.

There is a PHP lib, written completely in PHP, that allows you to do exactly what you want.

Here's an article about how it works, including the source code:
http://phpmyweb.net/2012/04/26/write-an-awesome-plugin-system-in-php/

It allows you to register a function from a class to be hooked. So it basically executes your code first, and then you determine wether you want to call the original function too after your code has been executed.

Comment: the link is no longer valid :(

Comment: Archive, Gives clue to use ```static function wrap()
{
    // self::PROTOCOL = "file";
    stream_wrapper_unregister(self::PROTOCOL);
    stream_wrapper_register(self::PROTOCOL, __CLASS__);
}
```
To implement file protocol yourself so I guess you can textually inject yourself into any php file read. Unfortunately full code link inside is also dead.
https://web.archive.org/web/20120623044534/http://phpmyweb.net/2012/04/26/write-an-awesome-plugin-system-in-php/